# Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi can't use

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have installed 16.04 on HP Zhan 66, but I find I can't use my Wi-Fi.
The network is as follows:

[image: The network]

I have run `sudo lshw -C network`, it shows:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
     description:network controller
     product: Intel Corportation
     ......
```

My network controller is *Intel Corporation Device[8086:9df0](rev 11) Subsystem:Intel Corporation Device[8086:0034]*.

Could anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Why did you install 16.04? It will be EoL very soon.

Comment: FYI:  16.04 means the 2016-April release, which comes with a *standard* supported life of 5 years, so it'll reach it's EOL on 2021-April. Unless you're aware of this, and this is only a *relatively* short term project, you might want to consider using a more recent release of Ubuntu (*with much more of it's supported life remaining*)

Answer (score 0):

Go to additional drivers and select the open source driver installed. If it is not available, install additional drivers in the terminal, using:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```